# How to add dependent project in build.sbt for running sbt compile

Tags: sbt

I am new to sbt build. 
I would like to add java files of a dependent project (say Proj A) to my compiling project (Proj B).
Running sbt compile in Proj B throws error that dependent project's java package/classes are not found.
I went through the link: https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html but its not clear to me add this dependency to make it work.

I tried adding a below line in build.sbt, but it didnt work.
lazy val projB = project.dependsOn(/projA)

Updated

## build.sbt of projB:

```
organization := "com.org"

name := "projB"

version := "1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
 )

lazy val projB = project.dependsOn(projA)

// the library dependencies of springframework here
```

## **build.sbt of Proj A:**

```
organization := "com.org"

name := "proj A"

version := "1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
 "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
 )

// the library dependencies of springframework here
```

When i do sbt compile on proj B, it throws error the dependent classes are not found. Class Hbase is in Proj A.

```
[error] import com.org.config.Hbase;
[error] **\hbase\HbaseDAO.java:38:1:
cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class Hbase
[error]   location: class com.org.hbase.HbaseDAO
[error]         private Hbase hbase;
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) javac returned non-zero exit code
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 29/08/2019 9:58:39 AM
```

**Updated build.sbt after the suggestion:**

```
inThisBuild(
 Seq(
   organization := "com.org",
   version := "1",
   resolvers ++= Seq(
   "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
   "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
  )
 )
)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(projA,projB)

lazy val projA = project.settings(
    // project A settings and library dependencies

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter- 
parent" % "2.1.6.RELEASE" pomOnly()

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter- 
web" % "2.1.6.RELEASE"

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-hadoop- 
hbase" % "2.3.0.RELEASE"

libraryDependencies += "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "7.0.0.pre5"

libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "5.0.0.Alpha2"

libraryDependencies += "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.4"

libraryDependencies += "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils-core" % 
"1.8.3"

libraryDependencies += "xerces" % "xercesImpl" % "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-yarn-server- 
nodemanager" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "2.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "2.1.1" pomOnly()

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.1.1"
)

lazy val projB = project
 .dependsOn(projA)
  .settings(
   // project B settings and library dependencies
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter- 
parent" % "2.1.6.RELEASE" pomOnly()

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter- 
web" % "2.1.6.RELEASE"

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-hadoop- 
hbase" % "2.3.0.RELEASE"

libraryDependencies += "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "7.0.0.pre5"

libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "5.0.0.Alpha2"

libraryDependencies += "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.4"

libraryDependencies += "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils-core" % 
"1.8.3"

libraryDependencies += "xerces" % "xercesImpl" % "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-yarn-server- 
nodemanager" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % 
"2.10.0.pr2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "2.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "2.1.1" pomOnly()

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.1.1"

)
```

An error is thrown while sbt compile after the below library dependency in both project settings projA and projB

```
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter- 
web" % "2.1.6.RELEASE"
```

')' expected but string literal found is thrown for this line in projA settings and

';' expected but string literal found is thrown for this line in projB settings.

I couldnt get much clue with this err.

Comment: Hi Siva. Could you show the relevant parts of your `build.sbt`? When you add `.dependsOn` do you get an error? It should be `lazy val projB = project.dependsOn(projA)` (no slash, but I assume it was just a typo)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Updated the question with more details. I am also new to sbt and might be completely wrong in the way i am doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the two snippets you posted, I'm guessing that you have two separate `build.sbt` files, one for each subproject. This makes them independent and one project just doesn't see the other. While it may be possible to have multiple `build.sbt` files for the subprojects, it's recommended to define the whole multiproject build in a single `build.sbt` file in the root of the project.

For example, if you structure your project like this:

```
├── project
│  ├── build.properties
│  └── plugins.sbt
├── projA
│  └── src
├── projB
│  └── src
└── build.sbt
```

Then you can put all the build settings and subproject relations in the root `build.sbt`:

```
inThisBuild(
  Seq(
    organization := "com.org",
    version := "1",
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
      "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
    )
  )
)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(projA, projB)

lazy val projA = project
  .settings(
    // project A settings and library dependencies
  )

lazy val projB = project
  .dependsOn(projA)
  .settings(
    // project B settings and library dependencies
  )
```

Then if you launch an sbt shell from the root of the project, you can call `compile` (or any other task) to compile both `projA` and `projB`, or you can call `projA/compile` to compile that subproject specifically.

You are already reading documentation, so you know where to find more information. Notice that the link you provided points to the old documentation, at the top there is a banner pointing to the new page: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html

Comment: Thanks @laughedelic. I am still having few issues. Updated the post with latest build.sbt contents after this text: **Updated build.sbt after the suggestion**

Comment: You need to add commas between settings inside `.settings(...)`

Comment: Thank you @laughedelic. It helped. My project is compiling successfully now. Thanks a lot for your help.